# EJS error on es6 Template Literals

Tags: yeoman, lodash, ejs, template-literals

I'm creating a Yeoman Express app generator and using a template js file that contains template literals. 
I want the output file to contain this line

```
app.use(`/api/${apiVersion}`, apiRoutes);
```

but I think ${apiVersion} is being interpreted as a template value and giving me the error

```
ReferenceError: apiVersion is not defined
    at eval (lodash.templateSources[2]:9:10)
    at copy.process (/.../node-microservice/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/copy-tpl.js:11:58)
```

How do I get around this without having to just use

```
app.use('/api/' + apiVersion, apiRoutes);
```

?? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to Yeoman supporting lodash style templating, which conflicts with ES6 template strings.

The fix is to force Yeoman to only use EJS style template delimiters by passing the following options object to the template copy routine (as the last parameter):

```
this.fs.copyTpl(
  this.templatePath('_foo.js'),
  this.destinationPath(`foo.js`),
  variables,
  { interpolate: /<%=([\s\S]+?)%>/g }
);
```

(Reference: http://mammal.io/articles/yeoman-generators-es6/).

Another somewhat hackier workaround is to embed the desired line of code in a string inside an EJS template tags:

```
<%= 'app.use(`/api/${apiVersion}`, apiRoutes);' %>
```

Comment: EJS does not depend on any packages, though.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my bad. After further research it turns out this isn't a bug at all, but rather a feature of Yeoman that allows for lodash templating as well as EJS, and that gets mixed up with ES6 string templates.